# How to reload an webpage just once using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, resize, reload

I use resize to reload my page, but I want **just reload once** when page size small to bigger than 768px or big to simmer than 768px.
that my code now

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
 // if(document.body.clientWidth <= ipadWidth && x = 1){
  location.reload()
 // }
});
```

Comment: Is it too late to consider using flex box? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ it might take you a few hours to get your head round, but once you understand this then you wont have to update the page everytime the page is resized. Elements on the page would dynamically resize when the page size is changed. This concept is called responsive design

Comment: Why use javascript?  [CSS Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if that is what you are looking for but the code below will trigger each time only once on `resize` when the `innerWidth` is bigger than `768px` and once if it is smaller than `768px`.

**Note:** reloading the page is not an option in this case as all the values will reset after refreshing the page.

If you still wanted to reload the page then you would need to save these variables in your database but that is not enough since then you would need to track sessions for each user (even with that there are many scenarios to consider) which is definitely an overkill.

My suggestion is to ultimately avoid force refreshing.

If you provide more information on why you would want to force reload the page then possibly I could suggest a better solution to your problem.

If your issue is with **styling the page according to the screen size** then use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) instead.

For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  your CSS here
}
```

In above case your `CSS` rules would be active until the browser resizes to above `768px`. After that, the default `CSS` rules in your code would be active.

```js
let isSmall = false
let isBig = false
$(window).resize(function(){
   if (window.innerWidth >= 768 && !isBig) {
      isBig = true
      //location.reload()
      console.log('big once')
   }
   if (window.innerWidth < 768 && !isSmall) {
       isSmall = true
       //location.reload()
       console.log('small once')
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**
I updated the answer in order to give you a few examples of how you can use `JS` to conditionally show and hide elements.

I included two examples.

The first example on resizing the window - which is a bit expensive in terms of performance.

The second one is when the page loads - the check happens only once, on the first load.

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
   if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
     $(".choiceSubject_btn").show();    
   }else {
      $(".choiceSubject_btn").hide();   
   }
})
 
 
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
    $(".choiceSubject_btn").show();     
   }else {
      $(".choiceSubject_btn").hide();   
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="choiceSubject_btn">my button<h4></h4><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></button>
```

Comment: It use js to show and hide div, so I don't know how to change like @media this other code`<div class="choiceSubject_btn"><h4></h4><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></div>`
  `if(document.body.clientWidth <= ipadWidth){
  // parent.document.location.reload();
  $(".choiceSubject_btn").show();
  $(".choiceSubject_btn h4").text(subject);
  $(".choiceSubject").addClass("class-list4").hide();`